# get non-rotated rectangle just big enough to enclose rotated rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Rectangle drawn on a Canvas and it is rotated (any degree) and I'd like to get a non-rotated outer rectangle just big enough to enclose the rotated rectangle. how can I go about doing this? PS: I do have the RotateTransform that was used to rotate the inner rectangle in the first place.

Comment: get a pencil and paper,and solve this problem by some simple trigonometry(Pythagoras)... its not that hard,i think...??

Comment: I'm more interested in the possible solutions for this, yes I could do some trigonometry, I could compute all four corners.. or could I use [GeneralTransform.TransformBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.generaltransform.transformbounds.aspx)? or are there even other options?

Comment: @YAHOOOOO To his defence, I can't really see how pythagoras is a practical way of computing a bounding rectangle of 4 points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the min/max of the x/y values of all the corners transformed. There is a built in functionality for this in WPF:

```
GeneralTransform transform = yourRect.TransformToVisual(yourCanvas);
Rect bounds = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0,0, yourRect.ActualWidth, yourRect.ActualHeight));
```

Comment: thanks, this is a lot easier than computing all of it yourself and works like a charm, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Compute the four corners and from them derive min/max-X/Y.